# Update With Inner Join Running Too Slow

Tags: mysql

Can somebody help optimizing the query below. The tr_marketshare table contains just 84000 records and query is taking 6 minutes and 19 seconds to execute.

```
UPDATE tr_marketshare
INNER JOIN
(SELECT YEAR, MONTH, Door, Category, Category_Sales,Country 
 FROM tr_marketshare
 WHERE Brand = 'Gucci'
 AND Account = 'Wojooh' 
 AND Category='MU') MS
ON tr_marketshare.Door = MS.Door
AND tr_marketshare.Year = MS.Year
AND tr_marketshare.Month = MS.Month
AND tr_marketshare.Account='Wojooh'
AND tr_marketshare.Country = MS.Country
AND tr_marketshare.Category = 'MU'
AND tr_marketshare.Brand <> 'Gucci'
SET tr_marketshare.Category_Sales = MS.Category_Sales;
```

The schema information is as below.

ID and Year are Integer. 
Category_Sales is float
Rest of the fields are of Varchar type.

Thanks.

Comment: What fields have indexes?

Comment: Only ID has index. I created indexes on Month, Account, Country and Brand but that did not speed up the query performance.

Comment: may be that is the problem. Why don't you have secondary indices on other columns of interest for the join?

Comment: That is most likely your problem. You should run an EXPLAIN https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html on your query and see what columns are hurting you the most

Comment: Did you try adding columns to other fields like Door, Year and Category? If so, did you notice any improvement with it?

Comment: I created indexes on Month, Account, Country and Brand but that did not make any difference.

Comment: I would never have thought about using items which are not selected in the sub query in the on clause - what happens if you move AND tr_marketshare.Account='Wojooh'  AND tr_marketshare.Category = 'MU'
AND tr_marketshare.Brand <> 'Gucci' to where clause?